# Android- accessibility service - performGlobalAction() returns false

Tags: android, android-service-binding, accessibility

Please don't think my question as a duplicate of this one ([Accessibility Service - performGlobalAction() returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200046/accessibility-service-performglobalaction-returns-false))

I'm calling `performGlobalAction()` method in my accessibility service class `onStartCommand()` and parameter would be `GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS` or `GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME` or `GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK`

I've added this service to manifest with necessary meta-data, enabled accessibility service for my app in accessibility settings in my phone.

But still this method call returns false and action getting ignored.

In my accessibility service class, I've overridden `onServiceConnected()` method and just added a print statement and found that this method gets called very rarely and only when it's called, call to `performGlobalAction()` was successful.

My code for  accessibility service class looks similar to the one in above link. Do I miss something? Or is there any other proper way to start accessibility service?

Comment: Are you using a Xiaomi or Poco device? I have an app on Google Play that uses accessibility service. I'm also receiving records about performGlobalAction() returned false. I've collected these records with firebase for over 6 months. However, 99% of the records are from Xiaomi devices. I ran a lot of checks to see if accessibility service is enabled, even if it is enabled, the problem still exists.